# LaTeX and Text Statistics

Tags: latex, nlp

with LaTeX is there the possibility to generate a table with some statistics about the text written?

For exemple, one table with the number of nouns, phrases, paragraph, and some index about the variability or frequency of the words used.

Anyway, if there is not a package like this, how can I build one? I am very interested about this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Noone has ever implemented a natural language processing toolkit (NLTK) for LaTeX. In principle, this is possible, but TeX as a programming language isn't particularly well suited for this task.

So I suggest looking for one of the existing NLTKs (e.g., python-nltk) and do the statistics with it and feed back the result to LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX code is just plain text with control sequences.

You can use `detex` to remove all comments and control sequences, leaving you with plain text which you could feed through any NLTK you like.

The result of that can be formatted as a table and `\input` into the document.